# code a file to 1/0 binary file and reconstruct the original file from it in c++

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream

I'm trying to write a c++ code to read file and code it as (1/0) binary, then get the original file from the (1/0) file.
I have to reconstruct the original file from 1/0 binary file in some other computer, so 1/0 and how to reconstruct it is very important to me.

the cause is, my output file is smaller than the original file. for example if I have a 6.6 kb jpeg image the reconstructed file is about 6.4 kb.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

ofstream myOutput;
ifstream mySource;

int main()
{        

mySource.open("im1.jpg", ios_base::binary);
myOutput.open("im2.jpg", ios_base::binary);


unsigned char buffer;
unsigned char recBuffer;
unsigned int ascii;

if (mySource.is_open())
{
    while (!mySource.eof())
    {
    // code
    mySource >> buffer;
    ascii = static_cast<unsigned int>(buffer);
    cout<< bitset<8>(ascii) << endl;

    // reconstruction
    recBuffer = static_cast<char>(ascii);
    myOutput << recBuffer;
    }
}

mySource.close();
myOutput.close();

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

">>" operation will ignore whitespaces by default, in order to avoid this ignorance! you should set "noskipws" falg, There are other flags too, for example "skipws" or "hex", These flags are called "manipulators" in c++ and you can read about them in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

In this situation you should modify your code and add "noskipws":

```
while (!mySource.eof())
{
    // code
    mySource >> std:noskipws >>buffer;
    myOutput << recBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The most naive solution I can think of might look like this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream mySource("im1.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream myOutput("im2.jpg", std::ios::binary);

    for (char c; mySource.get(c); )
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << "\n";
        myOutput.put(c);
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking you should probably check for write errors, too:

```
        if (!myOutput.put(c))
        { 
            std::cerr << "Write error!\n";
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring whitespace in your input. Just change

```
while (!mySource.eof()) {
    mySource >> buffer;
```

with

```
while (mySource.get(buffer)) {
```

(and change `unsigned char buffer` for `char buffer`) and you should be ok...